# Weblogic 12c stickiness issue

Tags: java, c#, c, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

I am building a cluster environment with weblogic 12c as application server and I am using weblogic as LOADBALANCER,

my problem that every time I send the request to the load balancer it sends it to  a different node although it should send it to the same node !!

I am sure there is a missing property to enable affility (stickiness).

any suggestions guys !

Comment: Without further information , this post may assist you http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/oracle.htm
I am assuming you are using theWebLogic Proxy Plug-In and not Weblogic proxy for apache ..

Comment: Need more details on your configuration for anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: What details you want that may help ?

Comment: @KennethClark i edited my question is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using " WebLogic Proxy Plug-In " - can you confirm this is true.

The default loadbalancing algorithm is round robin When using weblogic proxy plug-in hence the behaviour you are observing is expected.

Session Stickiness comes into play only when you have an application which is using sessions, and you have defined WLCookieName parameter to the correct cookie name value in the plug-in.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e14395/plugin_params.htm#CIHFFGEB

Tell us what request are you sending to the loadbalancer ? 
is it to a static resource (like index.htm) 
or is it to an application where you are maintaining a session.

Share some bit of the plugin configuration you have done.

Comment: I am using WebLogic Server with the HttpClusterServlet as a proxy server, is this same as weblogic proxy plugin?

about WLCookieName we left everything as default values.

and about the requests, we have a web application with jsp's and servlets that are deployed on the nodes. and the load balancer forward randomly to the nodes!

Thanks a lot for your response.
waiting your response.

Comment: yes HttpClusterServlet is the same as proxy plugin (this name is used in context of apache)  you mentioned Jsp's and servlets, are you starting a session ? whats your session id ?

Comment: At the first login the user take a sessio id ( hashcode) so the cookie value is UserSessionId!primaryServer!SecondaryServer but after one or two request the values of primary and secondary are swappped. Although the servers are up !                                     I really apprichiate your help.

Comment: what is the "cookie-name" that your application is using ? if its different from the default JSESSIONID then you will have to define WLCookieName parameter. If you set the flag debug ALL and then make the same request, you might be able to get a clue on why you are seeing the behaviour.